# Remote Json with domain Api key

Tags: php, json, curl, jsonp

Here is my situation.

1. mydomain.com wants to get a remote json from remotedomain.com
2. mydomain.com has the api key given by remotedomain.com
3. from mydomain.com, in html/php this works, I see the json:

   `<a href="http://remotedomain.com?data=xx&key=xx&action=json">Get the Json</a>`
4. Than same link from chrome o any other nav does not work ( invalid key error ).  This is correct.
5. PROBLEM, I cant seem that json with php(Error 403) or js(MIME transfer error).

I have tried JSONP, Curl, fopen, .ajax get, file_get_contents etc.

Running out of Ideas.  HELP

You can ask for an API and test it yourself.

http://www.idealista.com/labs/api.htm

Api doc http://www.idealista.com/labs/api.htm?action=help#json

Its explained very well and should work.  So I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I have tried.  It is a sample json, with.

```
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
```

}

$returned_content = get_data('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker')

Also

```
var app = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker';
$.ajax({
url: app,
async: false,
dataType: "jsonp",
jsonp: "jsoncallback",
type:"GET",
success: function(html){
   console.log($(html));
},
error: function(){
}
```

});

Actually
https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/

is the closest I have been able to get it

These are just sample json.  The real json can only be seen with an api key

Comment: Where is the code enlaced with fluffy rainbows so we can see where a ray of sunshine made it hard to see the error? Ahum... Sorry... Do you have any code samples for us?

Comment: "from mydomain.com, in html/php this works" and later "PROBLEM, I cant seem that json with php" - so which one is it? Please correct your question accordingly.

Comment: could you provide the code of your request implementation?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
/* Loading JSON objects using JSONP */
(function($) {
    var url = 'https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
    
})(jQuery);

</script>`

Comment: `$contents = @file_get_contents('https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker');
var_dump($http_response_header);`

Comment: Hope it helps.  Sample json response can be seen here http://www.idealista.com/labs/api.htm?action=help#json